# PHP Array to XML, but format differently

Tags: php, xml

I have a PHP array that creates an xml file successfully.. however the format inside the XML file is what I need changed. currently, it produces this:

```
<markers>
    <marker>
        <info1></info1>
        <info2></info2>
    </marker>
</markers>
```

I need it to display like so:

```
<markers>
    <marker info1="43.5" info2="-79.6888888888889" />
</markers>
```

Here is the PHP code I am using to create the XML file from the PHP Array

```
// creating object of SimpleXMLElement
$xml_student_info = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><markers></markers>");

// function call to convert array to xml
array_to_xml($store,$xml_student_info);

//saving generated xml file
$xml_student_info->asXML('xmltest.xml');


// function defination to convert array to xml
function array_to_xml($store, &$xml_student_info) {
    foreach($store as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if(!is_numeric($key)){
                $subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("$key");
                array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            }
            else{
                $subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("marker");
                array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            }
        }
        else {
            $xml_student_info->addChild("$key","$value");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your script is using always the `addChild` which effectively adds a child. You need to use [addAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php) on "marker" to add the 2 attributes.

Comment: After doing that, the error I get is "Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object in" and its referring the the bottom addChild line.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the method addAttribute.
Have a look at my code below :)

```
<?php
$xml_student_info = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><markers></markers>");

$store = array(
                array('attr1' => 'test', 'attr2' => 'test'),
                array('attr3' => 'test', 'attr4' => 'test'),
            );
array_to_xml($store, $xml_student_info);

$xml_student_info->asXML('xmltest.xml');

function array_to_xml($store, &$xml_student_info) {
    foreach($store as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $child = $xml_student_info->addChild("marker");
            foreach($value as $k => $v) {
                $child->addAttribute("$k","$v");
            }
        } else {
            $child = $xml_student_info->addChild("marker");
            $child->addAttribute("$key","$value");
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<markers><marker attr1="test" attr2="test"/><marker attr3="test" attr4="test"/></markers>
```